# Move to rotated direction [2D] [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sheep which is rotating to random direction. Question is how to make it move all the time in the direction it was rotated (rotation changes every 5 seconds).
Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Sheep : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float SheepMovementSpeed = 30f;
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("SheepRandomRotate", Random.Range(3f, 4.9f), 5f);
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void SheepRandomRotate ()
    {
        var dir = new Vector2(Random.Range(-10, 10), Random.Range(-10, 10));
        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle + 90, Vector3.forward);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same Vector3.forward you used in your rotation

```
transform.position += (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

Comment: Yes, or in FixedUpdate

Comment: transform.position += (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * SheepMovementSpeed);

Comment: help pleaseee:(

Comment: its in 2d btw .

Answer (score 0):

In Update 
transform.up is up relative to the rotation. So if the camera is facinf forward that should work for your sprite.
    transform.Translate(transform.up* Time.deltaTime * SheepMovementSpeed )

Comment: try transform.Translate(Vector3.up* Time.deltaTime * SheepMovementSpeed )

Comment: transform.Translate(SheepMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, SheepMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0); this moves sheep but in wrong directions